# If IE don't show object [Header within Wordpress]

Tags: php, html, wordpress, object, if-statement

Looking to point IE browsers at a static image rather than the object I've created on the medio.com homepage.

This is the header_block php file that runs the object:

```
<!--Start of Product Banner-->
```

```
<object data=http://prep.medio.com/dash/graphless.html width="450" height="350"> <embed src=http://prep.medio.com/dash/graphless.html id=sgraph width="450" height="350"> </embed> Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.
```

```
<?php
        if (@$data['banner_position'] == "right")
        {
            include("block_header_banner_text.php");
            include("block_header_banner_media.php");

        } else {
            include("block_header_banner_media.php");
            include("block_header_banner_text.php");
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

I would love to say basically:

if Chrome, Safari, Opera, Firefox: show object. else: don't show object. Or vice versa if that makes more sense.

IE 9 and 10 display the object fine. It's really IE 8 and lower that doesn't.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have ie6-8 classes/ids set via conditional tags on your html tag?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just commenting out the `<object>` with MS comment blocks?

```
<!--[if !IE]> <-->
    <object>...</object>
<!--> <![endif]-->

or

<!--[if gte IE 9]> <-->
    <object>...</object>
<!--> <![endif]-->
```